# Tracking mouse position works only in webkit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating/showing a span tag at the position of the user in a div tag:

```
var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
$("#test").css({"left" : event.pageX - parentOffset.left - 20, "top":event.pageY - parentOffset.top}).fadeIn("fast");
```

This works great in webkit browsers, aka Chrome, Opera, etc.
Firefox doesn't even show the span tag, nothing happens, the console doesn't even output error codes.

Is there a solution for all browsers?
Thanks so far

Simplified jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q7PSs/

Comment: Please provide an example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or in another online tool.

Comment: probably you should normalize event e = jQuery.event.fix(e);

Comment: I created a fiddle and it works in webkit again, but not in FF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the JS console in firefox you will see that there's an error on each click: `ReferenceError: event is not defined`. You need to pass the event object to the event handler.

http://jsfiddle.net/q7PSs/1/

```
$("#par").click(function(event) {
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked - stillw ondering why I didn't see anything. Well nevermind

Comment: Ah yeah, I see you mentioned that. I guess check in the FF console that the 'JS' button is toggled and the 'errors' item is checked under the dropdown?